# Does a Vector Autoregression Model truly avoid circular function issues?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, forecasting, vector-autoregression

Let's say you have a VAR model that estimates GDP and Unemployment among many other variables using a certain number of lags.  This VAR model can estimate or regress GDP using Unemployment.  And, it can do the reverse too.  It can also do Granger Causality analysis between these two variables to analyze the direction of the causality and Impulse Response Function to measure the intensity of this directional causality.  But, can it truly forecast several periods out both GDP and Unemployment (Hold Out test situation)?

I would think once you run out of lags, this VAR model could not forecast for periods beyond the lags because then it has to rely on estimates of both variables to forecast out the specific variable you want to forecast.  And, at this stage you run into a circular function situation.

Answer (score 2):

With VAR models you can predict as many steps ahead as you like. When the future horizon increases, you will eventually run out of observed values to base your forecasts on. Then you just substitute the required observed values with their forecasts and iterate forward. Here is an example of VAR(1) (I skip the intercept for brevity):
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \Phi x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t \\
\hat x_{t+1|t} &= \Phi x_{t} \quad \text{(have not run out of observed values yet)}\\
\hat x_{t+2|t} &= \Phi \hat x_{t+1} = \Phi^2 x_{t} \quad \text{(have run out of observed values, thus substitute)}\\
\hat x_{t+3|t} &= \Phi \hat x_{t+2} = \cdots = \Phi^3 x_{t} \\
&\cdots \\
\hat x_{t+h|t} &= \Phi \hat x_{t+h-1} = \cdots = \Phi^h x_{t} \\
\end{aligned}
where $x_t$ is a multivariate time series of interest, $\Phi$ is a square matrix of coefficients and $\varepsilon_t$ is a multivariate time series of errors (innovations, shocks).

**Update** to include some information from the comments:
We are doing the best we can given that we only have current information but not future information. The fact that forecasts are mean reverting reflects an assumption on the data generating process (DGP). As Chris Haug points out, this is *a consequence of the linearity of the model, but it is not an approximation*. The behavior of the forecasts is actually optimal given the DGP. And as long as VAR is a good approximation of the DGP, I would not expect alternative forecasts to beat the ones by VAR, unless they employ some future information. But in the latter case, a fair comparison would add this information to the VAR model in terms of exogenous variables or the like.

Comment: when "you just substitute the required observed values with their forecasts and iterate forward"...  Isn't this a sort of circular function issue.  You have forecasts that end up just using forecasts as their independent variable inputs.  And, as you go forward you are using forecasts of forecasts of forecasts to estimate further forecasts.  Mathematically, does not this result in some sort of flattening out every forecasted value to some sort of average historical value?  And, by doing so you loose all real sensitivity to the economic environment.

Comment: @Sympa, *as you go forward you are using forecasts of forecasts of forecasts to estimate further forecasts* - right. Also, the answer to *Mathematically, does not this result in some sort of flattening out every forecasted value to some sort of average historical value?* is a Yes. However, in which sense do you think that *you loose all real sensitivity to the economic environment*? After all, we only have information as of time $t$, and we incorporate it (so we do not lose sensitivity there). However, we cannot incorporate future information about the economic environment that we do not have.

Comment: @Sympa, so briefly, we are doing the best we can given that we only have current information but not future information. The *flattening out every forecasted value to some sort of average historical value* is essentially caused by the forecasting problem being tough, not the forecast method being poor.

Comment: thanks for all the insights.  The forecasting environment I am in is where we are provided forecast-scenarios for a bunch of macroeconomic variables.  And, we are modeling-forecasting a dependent variable using those scenarios.  And, what we are considering is forecast two dependent variables, let's say Y1 and Y2.  Given this framework, a VAR model forecast would work as long as you do not run out of lags.  Once you do, you would run into the mentioned issues.  And, you would be better off regressing Y1 and Y2 separately using a multiple regression framework.

Comment: @Sympa, I see. It is hard to comment on that without some more details, though. Is there anything else I should address in my answer?

Comment: When you say "it is hard to comment on that without some more details"... what other details could I provide for you being able to customize your answer to my forecasting framework as specified?

Comment: @Sympa, well, if regressing Y1 and Y2 separately using a multiple regression framework is supposed to beat VAR, I suspect this is because VAR is not provided the information that is used in the multiple regressions, which is kind of unfair. Perhaps this information could be incorporated into the VAR in the form of exogenous regressors (yielding a VARX) or so? Though on the other hand, perhaps this discussion should be left for another thread as the current one is nicely self contained as is.

Comment: The multiple regression estimating Y1, the other one estimating Y2, and VAR would be provided the exact same information in terms of exogenous macroeconomic variables forecasting scenarios.  For my part, I don't see how VAR could leverage any useful information from the simultaneous forecasting of Y1 and Y2, and in turn use those respective forecasts to inform each other.  That's where the circular function comes in.

Comment: With VAR, once you go beyond the lags you simultaneously need the forecast of Y1 to forecast Y2... and the forecast of Y2 to forecast Y1 which gets you in the circular function hole.  Using separate regressions to forecast Y1 and Y2 separately (with the same set of exogenous macroeconomic variables forecast scenarios) gets you out of the hole.

Comment: @Sympa, separate regression ignore the relationship between (the lags of) Y1 and Y2. If this relationship is weak, this may be fine, but if it is considerable, ignoring it would mean throwing out information. The *circular function hole* allows reflecting the relationship. Regarding something from before: *a VAR model forecast would work as long as you do not run out of lags. Once you do, you would run into the mentioned issues.* The forecast works also after that, and the *issues* are just reflecting characteristics of the modeled relationship and the amount of available information there is.

Comment: Richard, your earlier statement "@Sympa, as you go forward you are using forecasts of forecasts of forecasts to estimate further forecasts - right. Also, the answer to Mathematically, does not this result in some sort of flattening out every forecasted value to some sort of average historical value? is a Yes" seem to contradict your most recent comment.

Comment: @Sympa, hmm, I do not think it does, but perhaps I did not express myself clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

After giving it some thought, I think the straight forward answer is that VAR does not resolve the circular function situation as framed in my question.  And, frankly I don't think any other methodology can.  You can't use A to forecast B at the same time as you use B to forecast A once you go beyond any related lagged variables.

The key is "at the same time" and "once you go beyond any related lagged variables."

Practitioners often think they can by relying on forecasts once you go beyond the lags.  But, that is not the same thing.  You very soon are relying on the forecast of a forecast to forecast the next period.  You end up with some mean-reverting process whereby you probably would be better off to simply use a simple average as your long term forecast.

Comment: The conditional expectation $h$ steps ahead for a VAR($p$) with $h>p$ is *exact* and does not "rely" on forecasts. The fact that the conditional expectation is the *same* as applying the matrix $\Phi$ to the forecasts is simply a consequence of the linearity of the model, but it is *not* an approximation. There is nothing circular about this situation.

Comment: @ChrisHaug, excellent point (that I missed in my answer).

Comment: I am unclear how you could not "rely" on forecast going forward as specified.  Similarly, the conditional expectation I would think would become increasingly mean-reverting the further you go out on your forecast.

Comment: The two-step forecast for a VAR(1) is just $\Phi^2 x_t$, so what you are *relying* on is your estimate for $\Phi$. Phrasing it as a "forecast of a forecast of a forecast" makes it sound like some disastrous sequence of approximations on top of each other, when in fact the only approximation here is the standard one that you make whenever you fit any model. It's also not clear to me why you think that the forecast being mean-reverting is somehow bad; if the data is well-represented by a VAR(p), then that is exactly what should happen.

Comment: "The standard one you make whenever you fit any model" is not true for any non autoregressive models.  They do not rely on any estimation of either Y or X variables to forecast Y. Also, the "data is well-represented ... would entail that it is mean-reverting" is only true for the history or learning sample.  It is not true for any forecast.